# duplicate plist in xcode causes all values to be strings?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I am using plists to store preset settings for my iOS app.  I've created a default plist that I would like to copy and use as a template for all of my presets.  However, when I duplicate the plist in Xcode, all of the types become strings!  Any ideas why this happens or how to fix this?

As an example, my default.plist looks like this in Xcode

```
-mono       boolean     NO
-name       string      default
-portamento number      0.001
```

and after i duplicate it into a new file:

```
-mono       string      NO
-name       string      default
-portamento string      0.001
```

Thanks!!

//////Thanks Michael Dautermann for the answer to this.  When I created the .plist file in Xcode, I had appended .plist manually.  This resulted in a file that looked great in Xcode, but wasn't actually an .xml file.  As a result, the datatypes were not included in the source code.  So, simply create a .plist file (and don't append .plist) and all is well.

Comment: please edit your question to show what the plist looks like before and after you duplicate the plist.

Comment: Are you copying directly in Xcode or are you using Finder?

Comment: More detail is needed. How do you "duplicate" (and why)? Also what you are showing are not standard XML format plist files, are you just summarizing their content?

Comment: I'm duplicating using "file>duplicate" from Xcode's menu.  I'm summarizing the content... However, that is what the plist looks like in Xcode's plist editor.  I'm not formatting the plist myself.

Comment: Hello Olynoise... I'd like to see one more edit to your question.  Could you cut/paste the Source Code view of your default.plist and the copied file? I.E. it should have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the top & `<plist version="1.0">` on the third line. The reason I ask to see this is that I suspect what you're trying to copy is not a true plist file, at least in terms of what Xcode can parse and duplicate.  When I create my own plist file in a test project with your key/value pairs and do File->Duplicate on it, it copies perfectly fine.

Comment: Ah... I see.  You are correct in that the .plist that I'm editing isn't a properly formatted .xml file. I see where I went wrong  - I gave it a .plist extension as per a tutorial and the file didn't properly encode the datatypes for me!  thanks!!